# Adding CORS headers to my NodeJS ExpressJS API but not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, cors

I have this API that I have created that is called from an angularJS app through a POST request.
Everything is working fine except that, because the API and the app are not hosted on the same server, I have this Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism blocking the post request, unless I activate the CORS add-on in Chrome, which I would like to avoid.

Apparently, the solution lies in the headers, and I have found some very promising information, but there is something I must be doing wrong because I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my code:

1. parentheses.js (where my post request happens)

   ```
   const parenthesesChecker = require('./checker.js');

   const express = require('express'), bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const router = express.Router();

   router.use(bodyParser.json());

   router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
     const stringCheck = ({
       string: req.body
     });
     if (parenthesesChecker(stringCheck.string.string).result === true) {
       res.status(200).json({
         "isValid": true
       });
     } else {
       res.status(200).json({
         "isValid": false,
         "errorDetails": {
             "preceedingParentheses": `${parenthesesChecker(stringCheck.string.string).preceeding}`,
             "erroneosParentheses": `${parenthesesChecker(stringCheck.string.string).erroneos}`
         }
       });
     };
   });

   module.exports = router;
   ```
2. app.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();

   const parenthesesRoutes = require('./parentheses');
   app.use('/parentheses', parenthesesRoutes);

   module.exports = app;
   ```
3. server.js

   ```
   const http = require('http');
   const app = require('./app')

   const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

   const server = http.createServer(app);
   server.listen(port);
   ```

When I try to use the app that makes the post request to the API, without activating the CORS add-on in my chrome browser, I get this error message in the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://parentheses-api.herokuapp.com/parentheses' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: `Why is this not working` - exactly what error are you getting

Comment: I see you `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` ... requests with credentials can't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: you need to set up cors on the server that will receive the api calls not on the client doing them. So I'd expect it on server.js instead of parenthsese.js.

Comment: Please give a [mre] including the outputs from the console and network tab, not just *"not working"*. Most likely you're seeing the preflight OPTIONS request, which you don't currently handle, failing.

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just that I need to activate the CORS add-on in my chrome in order to get a response. Which is exactly what I want to avoid

Actually you are right about ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` but I commented it out in my code. It still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @LelioFaieta how would I go about doing that? what part of the code should I move from ```parentheses.js``` to ```server.js``` ?

Comment: @LelioFaieta server uses app which uses parentheses, this is all server not client code; I've re-ordered the snippets to make that more obvious.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not getting any error, it's just that I need to activate the CORS add-on in my chrome in order to get a response. Otherwise I get nothing, and I suppose the post request is not getting through?

Comment: So did you look in the network tab to see what that tells you about the request? What makes you think you "get nothing"?

Comment: So, the problem I have is that the CORS mechanism block my requests. I do get an error  message that I will add to my initial question

Comment: *"I am not getting any error"* or *"I do get an error message"*? You currently have both in your question, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check` - this is the OPTIONS request, as I mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222007/adding-cors-headers-to-my-nodejs-expressjs-api-but-not-working#comment113565521_64222007), you don't handle it at all. Either use the standard middleware linked below, or read up on how to correctly handle CORS yourself (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).